# What is the best way to create a portrait and a landscape view for one controller [Storyboard]?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, orientation

Storyboards are an awesome feature - but is there a possibility to create a lanscape and a portrait view for one controller? What is the best way to do that?

I found a lot on StackOverflow, from copying a storyboard to add subviews for each orientation. It would be great, if there is a better way to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosizing works only on simplest straighforward cases. If you have to tweak just a little bit the end result, it becomes too hard. What I do to make this much more visual is I set autosizing, then duplicate the portrait view right for the same controller in the same xib and rotate it to landscae. Then I adjust the positions. But before that I set tag properties for each control. So I create actually 2 duplicate views, 1 portrait and 1 landscape and since the tags are the same, during "willRotateTo..." or "didRotateTo.." I copy the .frame property of each control from the duplicate View that I visually adjusted in xib, and that puts the control where I wanted.
I can even add animation along the way.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use autosizing of subviews for each UIViewController of your storyboard. It's the cleanest way of managing rotation.

Check: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_5_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to create multiple scenes for every orientation. You're supposed to use autoresizing, springs and struts, custom implementations of several rotation methods and respond to notifications.